# BaseAdapter crashes on notifyDataSetChanged() call

Tags: android

I have created a custom listview and adapter by extending BaseAdapter. Every time I try and call notifyDataSetChanged() on the adapter, the program crashes with a NullPointerException.

This is my code for creating the listview and adapter:

```
private ArrayList<MessageItem> convList = new ArrayList<MessageItem>();

// setup list view
ListView list = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.conv_list);
MessageAdapter dataAdapter = new MessageAdapter(this, convList);
list.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
list.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

I try and update the listview by doing this within an AsyncTask everytime new data is received over the network:

```
protected class ConversationTask extends AsyncTask<Context, String, String>
    {   
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Context... arg0) {
            for (;;) {
                while (t_recv.messageQueue.isEmpty());
                publishProgress(t_recv.messageQueue.remove(t_recv.messageQueue.size() - 1));
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(String... i)
        {
            convList.add(new MessageItem("Name", "Msg"));
            dataAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }
```

A NullPointerException occurs on calling notifyDataSetChanged(). If I remove this call, the listview will only update if I press the back button, or show/hide the keyboard (i'm guessing this somehow triggers an update). So... am I doing something wrong here?

The code for the adapter is below if you need it:

```
public class MessageAdapter extends BaseAdapter
{
    private Context context;

    private ArrayList<MessageItem> listMessage;

    public MessageAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<MessageItem> listMessage) {
        this.context = context;
        this.listMessage = listMessage;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
        MessageItem entry = listMessage.get(position);
        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.message, null, false);
        }
        TextView tvName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvName);
        tvName.setText(entry.getName());

        TextView tvMsg = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvMsg);
        tvMsg.setText(entry.getMsg());

        return convertView;
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return listMessage.size();
    }
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return listMessage.get(position);
    }
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }
}
```

Each item in the list is a 'MessageItem' as shown below:

```
public class MessageItem
{
    private String name;
    private String msg;

    public MessageItem(String name, String msg) {
        this.name = name;
        this.msg = msg;
    }

    // Getter methods
    public String getName() { return name; }
    public String getMsg() { return msg; }
}
```

Also, the error is:

```
04-21 13:56:30.762: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(30024): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-21 13:56:30.762: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(30024): java.lang.NullPointerException
04-21 13:56:30.762: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(30024):     at com.client.Conversation.appendMessage(Conversation.java:129)
04-21 13:56:30.762: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(30024):     at com.client.Conversation.access$2(Conversation.java:122)
04-21 13:56:30.762: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(30024):     at com.client.Conversation$ConversationTask.onProgressUpdate(Conversation.java:170)
04-21 13:56:30.762: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(30024):     at com.client.Conversation$ConversationTask.onProgressUpdate(Conversation.java:1)
04-21 13:56:30.762: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(30024):     at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:432)
04-21 13:56:30.762: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(30024):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-21 13:56:30.762: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(30024):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:143)
04-21 13:56:30.762: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(30024):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5068)
04-21 13:56:30.762: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(30024):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-21 13:56:30.762: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(30024):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
04-21 13:56:30.762: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(30024):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:858)
04-21 13:56:30.762: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(30024):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
04-21 13:56:30.762: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(30024):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Thank you

Comment: Would you please share your `AsyncTask` implementation as well? Where is your `convList` member defined? It should be a class-level variable.

Comment: And what does your adb logcat says?

Comment: The stack trace of the NullPointerException itself could also be useful.

Comment: Thanks. The ArrayList<MessageItem> convList = new ArrayList<MessageItem>(); is a actual a private class variable (i just posted it there to simplify -- oops).

Comment: AsyncTask and stack trace was added to the post ^

Comment: So... If I add `dataAdapter.notifyDataSetInvalidated();` in the onCreate method of the main activity for example, it doesn't crash. It seems like it only works in the UI thread. I figured this would work through an AsynTask (since it can update UI from another thread). So how to I call `dataAdapter.notifyDataSetInvalidated();` from a different thread now? Thanks!

Comment: Not from a different thread. You're right, AsyncTask should work, the only thing i can think of going wrong is that your dataAdapter is null. You might have several `Caused by` clauses in your stack trace, that indicate the point of origin of the `NullPointerException` inside your code. It would help if you could provide that. Until then, would you please check with a breakpoint, whether the `dataAdapter` you are accessing from the `onProgressUpdate(String... i)` method has a value? Thanks!

Comment: exact code "((BaseAdapter) ((ListView)findViewById(R.id.conv_list)).getAdapter()).notifyDataSetChanged();" i try to execute...but still list not upping..rest of overrie method prety same...any idea/suggestion?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead of

```
dataAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

you should try

```
((ListView)findViewById(R.id.conv_list)).getAdapter().notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Is your `MessageAdapter dataAdapter` member also a private variable? I assume it is, otherwise you should have gotten compile errors. 
So if it is, make sure that you initialize that one, don't have inside your `onCreate` method an other declaration with the same name (this way your private class member would remain null!).

This line in your code suggests that you assign a local variable adapter to your `ListView`:

```
MessageAdapter dataAdapter = new MessageAdapter(this, convList);
```

Comment: Great! Changing `dataAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` to `((BaseAdapter) ((ListView)findViewById(R.id.conv_list)).getAdapter()).notifyDataSetChanged();` worked.

And yes, it would appear the dataAdapter only exists locally within onCreate() -- oops! Making this a class variable also fixes the issue. Thank you for you help.

Comment: You're welcome. Also, +1 for the exceptionally fast responses, and good, clear question.

Comment: I am doing this notifyDataSetChanged() from inside baseadapter... so, whatshould I need to do...

Comment: this.notifyDataSetChaged(); I don't see a reason why you should invoke it from inside a baseadapter implementation though.